# How can I use ifstream from my c++ Dll in my Unity project?

Tags: c#, c++, unity-game-engine, dll, fstream

I have to read a .json file with ifstream from a c++ dll, and I need to use that dll in Unity. I know that there's a problem with Unicode and ASCII, but I can't solve this problem
PS: I made convert_to_string myself, it extract an int from a certain string

In the header of the Dll I have:

```
int leggiCpp(string nomeFile);

extern "C" {
QUARTALIBRERIA_API int leggiCs(wstring nomeFile);
}
```

In the cpp of the Dll I have:

```
int leggiCpp(string nomeFile) {
ifstream _stream(nomeFile.c_str());
string temp;
_stream >> temp >> temp >> temp >> temp >> temp;
return convert_to_int(temp);
}

QUARTALIBRERIA_API int leggiCs(wstring nomeFile){

std::string str = std::string(nomeFile.begin(), nomeFile.end());
int daRit = leggiCpp(str);
return daRit;

}
```

In the Unity script I have:

```
[DllImport("QuartaLibreria.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
static extern unsafe int leggiCs(string nomeFile);


// Start is called before the first frame update
unsafe void Start()
{
    int temp = leggiCs("Assets/alzBraccioCorretto.json");
}
```

I have no compiling error, but the Unity program crashes and says: Runtime Error!

Program: This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.

Comment: You have neither `LeggiFile` declaration nor definition in your cpp file.

Comment: @KaenbyouRin Thank you, updated now! LeggiFile was leggiCs, I just forgot to change its name in both scripts. Other than that, do you have any suggestion?

Comment: And could you please provide what is the marco `QUARTALIBRERIA_API` expanded into? Because it is the calling convention and is needed in C# P/Invoke calls.

Comment: Never convert a binary file to a string you will corrupt the data and will never be able to fix issue. What type of file are you reading?  If it is binary you should read it into a byte[].

Comment: @jdweng I'm reading a json file.

Comment: @KaenbyouRin i'm new to programming, I copied my code's format from a tutorial... What should I write in my code to make it work?

Comment: Use a json library, don't try to parse the file yourself

Comment: You are using visual studio, right? Just hover over `QUARTALIBRERIA_API` and see the tool tip. Or alternatively, just click `QUARTALIBRERIA_API` and press F12.

Comment: @KaenbyouRin Yes, VS2017! I did it but I still have RunTime error.... What would you change in my code?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The function works fine, and I have a lot of code in the real C++ Dll, this is just a sample. What would you change in my script?

Comment: @jdweng thank you! What would you change in my code?

Comment: A string in c++ is a byte array that terminate with a '\0' while a string in c# is a class object that can be one or two bytes.  The two are not compatible.  In c# to create the c++ string you use BString.  Either  Marshal.StringToBSTR or Marshal.PtrToStringBSTR.  If the c++ is using unicode (two byte strings) it is using wchar so you use  Marshal.StringToHGlobalUni or  Marshal.PtrToStringUni

Comment: Sorry, I thought you said you needed to read a json file in C++.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I have a c# script that uses a dll written in c++, I have all the code in the dll and what I've shown is just an example. But what would you change to make it work?

Comment: In your `[DllImport("QuartaLibreria.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]` add a calling convention field. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.callingconvention?view=netframework-4.8 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.callingconvention?view=netframework-4.8. Since you don't know which calling convention you are using, try them all! (thiscall is very unlikely, however)

Comment: The C++ code needs to accept char* or wchar_t*